# Monotonic function in closed interval

Tags: calculus

I am reading a proof that a monotonic function in closed interval is integrable.

The proof uses the assumption that "Let assume that $f$ is increasing, therefore for all $x\in[a,b]$: $f(a)\le f(x)\le f(b)$  and $f$ **is bounded**"

Why can we assume that $f$ is bounded? maybe $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=\infty$?

Moreover if every monotonic function in closed interval is bounded then it also get it maximum and minimum values there?

Comment: Actually, Motonic function finite a.e is Lebesgue integrable.

Answer (score 10):

Because the function is defined on a *closed* interval. Since it is increasing, certainly its value at $b$ is maximum.

If we had that $\lim_{x\to b}=+\infty$, then either the function is not defined at $b$ (so the interval is not closed), or whichever (finite) value one assigns to $f$ at $b$ will violate monotonicty.

Comment: I did not pay attention to "the function is defined", thanks

Comment: Can open bracket functions be monotobic... They are not differentiable at end points and their limit also not exists at end points

Comment: Of course they can. A simple example is $f(x) = x$ on any open interval.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly $f(a)$ is a lower bound and $f(b)$ is an upper bound.  If $f$ is real-valued, then that makes $f$ bounded on the interval.

If $f$ is weakly increasing and $f(x)\uparrow\infty$ as $x\uparrow b$, then $f(b)=\infty$.  If $f$ is allowed to take values in $[-\infty,\infty]$, then that can happen.  However, it is conventional not to call a function "bounded" when it's bounded only by $+\infty$ or or $-\infty$.